# Service's BehaviorSubject set to null between two different component calls

Tags: angular, ionic4, behaviorsubject

Sorry this will be a long one.

I have a login page which, after successful login, feeds a UserService 's BehaviorSubject with users's token, then redirects to a agenda page.

This page lists some events, and if I click on the event's card,I am redirected to the event's details. This two pages are handled by the same service. This service depends on the UserService.
At the first page (listing), I can grab the UserService's BehaviorSubject, but it's like it is set to null when I go to the details.

Here are my pages and services (truncated if necessary) :

**user.service.ts**

```js
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class UserService {
      private baseUrl = 'http://frat/';
      private userSource = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
      public user$ = this.userSource.asObservable();

      constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

      login(user: User): Observable<HttpResponse<User>> {
        return this.httpClient
          .post(`${this.baseUrl}/login`, user, {
            observe: 'response'
          })
          .pipe(
            tap(async (response: HttpResponse<User>) => {
              // this.setUser(new User(response.body)); //  = new User(response.body);
          })
        );
      }

      public buildAuthorizationHeader(): string {
        return 'Basic ' + btoa(this.userSource.getValue().pseudo + ':' + this.userSource.getValue().password);
      }

      /**
       * Met à jour l'observable pour avertir les observateurs dans les composants.
       * @param user
       */
      setUser(value) {
        this.userSource.next(value);
      }
    }
```

**evenements.service.ts**

```js
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class EvenementsService {
      private baseUrl = 'http://frats/evenements';
      private user: User;
      private evenementsSource = new BehaviorSubject<Evenement[]>([]);
      private evenementSource = new BehaviorSubject<Evenement>(null);

      public evenements$ = this.evenementsSource.asObservable();
      public evenement$ = this.evenementSource.asObservable();

      constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private userService: UserService) {
        this.userService.user$.subscribe(user => {
          console.log('EvtSvc User : ', user);
          this.user = user;
        });
      }

      public getEvenements(): Observable<Evenement[]> {
        return this.httpClient
        .get<Evenement[]>(this.baseUrl, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: this.userService.buildAuthorizationHeader()
          }
        })
        .map((evts) => {
          return evts.map((e) => new Evenement(e));
        });
      }

      public getEvenementById(id): Observable<Evenement> {
        return this.httpClient
        .get<Evenement>(this.baseUrl + '/' + id,  {
          headers: {
            Authorization: this.userService.buildAuthorizationHeader()
          }
        })
        .map((evt) => new Evenement(evt));
      }

      public setEvenements(value) {
        this.evenementsSource.next(value);
      }

      public setEvenement(value) {
        this.evenementSource.next(value);
      }
    }
```

**agenda.page.ts** (which lists the events, works fine)

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-agenda',
      templateUrl: './agenda.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./agenda.page.scss'],
    })
    export class AgendaPage implements OnInit {
      private evenements: Evenement[] = [];
      public titre = 'Agenda';

      constructor(private evenementService: EvenementsService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.evenementService.evenements$.subscribe(evenements => this.evenements = evenements);
      }

      ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.loadData();
      }

      loadData(event = null) {
        this.evenementService.getEvenements().subscribe(evenements => {
          this.evenementService.setEvenements(evenements);
        });

        if (isNull(event) === false) {
          event.target.complete();
        }
      }
    }
```

**evenement.page.ts** (which has the userService's user as null, displayed after click on agenda's displayed event)

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-evenement',
      templateUrl: './evenement.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./evenement.page.scss'],
    })
    export class EvenementPage implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild('map', {read: false, static: false}) mapContainer: ElementRef;
      map: any;
      private id: number;
      private evenement: Evenement;
      private localisation: Localisation;
      public titre = 'Evénement';

      constructor(
        public route: ActivatedRoute,
        private cal: Calendar,
        private evenementService: EvenementsService,
        private launchNavigator: LaunchNavigator,
        private locSvc: LocalisationService,
        private userService: UserService
      ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'), 10);
        this.evenementService.evenement$.subscribe((evenement) => this.evenement = evenement);
      }

      ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.loadData();
      }

      loadData(): void {
        this.evenementService.getEvenementById(this.id).subscribe(evenement => {
          this.evenementService.setEvenement(evenement);
        });
      }
      ... other methods to make map and marker appear ...
    }
```

**login.page.ts**

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
    })
    export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

      private loginForm: FormGroup;
      public titre = 'Connexion';

      constructor(private userService: UserService, public alertController: AlertController, private router: Router) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
          login: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        });

        this.userService.user$.subscribe((user) => {
          console.log('Login user : ', user);
        });
      }

      login(form) {
        this.userService.login(form.value).subscribe((response) => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            this.userService.setUser(new User(response.body));
            this.router.navigateByUrl('agenda');
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          let message;

          if (error.status === 401) {
            message = 'Vos identifiants n\'ont pas été reconnus.';
          } else {
            message = 'Une erreur a eu lieu, veuillez retenter plus tard.';
          }

          this.presentAlert(message);
        });
      }

      async presentAlert(message) {
        const alert = await this.alertController.create({
          header: 'Erreur',
          subHeader: 'Un problème a eu lieu',
          message,
          buttons: ['OK']
        });

        await alert.present();
      }
    }
```

I can't figure out why the userService is like reset. Maybe another instance is created when entering on evenement.page.ts, but why so then ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: We're seeing that the `// this.setUser(new User(response.body)); //  = new User(response.body);` line is commented. That looks like the only place where the user, which is your BehaviorSubject, gets a value assigned.

Comment: Sorry, the value is assigned in another page, I will put it as an update.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this one is tricky.

On the agenda (listing) page, I use ion-cards with href attribute. When I tap, the detail is rendered, but the UserService is kinda reset.

```html
<ion-card button="true" href="'evenements/' + e.id" color="light" *ngFor="let e of evenements">
```

I replaced the href attribute by an (click) event, which calls router.navigateByUrl(event/id), and it does the trick !

```html
<ion-card button="true" (onclick)="showEvent(e.id)" color="light" *ngFor="let e of evenements">
```

```js
showEvent(id) {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('evenement/' + id);
}
```

I don't understand why it is so, if someone has an explanation ....

A least it works !